# is there any open source software for linux programming with system calls?

Tags: windows, development

i am currently working with Ubuntu GCC compiler and i run it on VMWARE .but i am looking for a open source software that can run on windows 8 or 8.1 platform which can code ,compiling ,run programs with linux/unix system calls.

Comment: In Windows 10, Microsoft promises an Ubuntu subsystem which will be capable of doing this. For now, your best option is to stick to a VM.

Comment: Technically if you're set on open-source, VirtualBox could be preferable. That is an Oracle product (boo), but I guess it does avoid using a vendor whose VM products are actually being litigated under the GPL right now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) developer tools and the `gcc-linux` cross-compiler to cross-compile on Windows for Linux.

Comment: If the program is cross-compiled with Linux as target, it won't run on that machine. If it's compiled with Windows as its target, the executable won't actually run on Linux.